# Get data from XML document

Tags: xml, python-3.x, pandas

I am struggling with figuring out getting data from a XML document. I am looking at this source: http://cbu.uz/uzc/arkhiv-kursov-valyut/xml/USD/2015-03-26/ and would like to extract the following data (4 columns 1 row):

```
<CcyNm_EN>U.S. Dollar</CcyNm_EN>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Rate>2484.15</Rate>
<date>24.03.2015</date>
```

Thus far I could make progress till here and no idea what to do further:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://cbu.uz/uzc/arkhiv-kursov-valyut/xml/USD/2015-03-26/'
xml_data = requests.get(url).content
root = et.fromstring(xml_data)
root.attrib
```

Any help and guidance is appreciated!

Comment: what does this have to do with pandas?

Comment: I wanted to store the outcome into 4x1 dataframe

Comment: But there's 9 elements, what dataframe do you want?

Comment: I need 4 out of those 9 (shown above) in a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to get the values. Basically you need to iterate over root node to find all child and extract the data.

Edit :  Updating answer to have output in Dataframe and have only four element in output.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://cbu.uz/uzc/arkhiv-kursov-valyut/xml/USD/2015-03-26/'
xml_data = requests.get(url).content
root = et.fromstring(xml_data)
required_tag = [ 'CcyNm_EN','Nominal','Rate','date']

root.attrib

data_dict = {}
for elem in root:
    for el in elem:  
        if el.tag in required_tag:
            data_dict.setdefault(el.tag,[]).append(el.text)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
```

output :

```
   CcyNm_EN   Nominal Rate     date
0 U.S. Dollar 1       2484.15  24.03.2015
```

Comment: thank you Sach. Would you be able to help structure the data into a dataframe? Will accept your answer soon.